# Error - The email address is badly formed. Xcode Swift Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a UI interface with authentication as an iOS app. I've come a long way from where I was originally but I cannot get past this error. I don't understand what I'm compiling incorrectly. Please take a look and help me out if you can.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        email.delegate = self
        password.delegate = self
        passwordConfirm.delegate = self
    }


    @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if password.text !=
            passwordConfirm.text{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
                }
                else{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

The goal is to then accept the user input from email.text and password.text and segue into the home screen after creating a new user in my Firebase console.

Comment: can you do a `print(email.text!)` before `Auth.auth().createUser(..` and post here the example of email you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has its own email validation which is like this 'abc@somedomain.com' so you need to pass a email address like this other wise it will keep throwing this error.